# How to get local time from UST in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am making an app using flutter, dart.
I am using some api to get sunrise time using longitude and latitude.
But the data I get is in UST time zone.
I want to convert it to local time zone.

In short I have location and I want to convert time to local time.

eg. I have time **"3:02:32 PM"** which is in **UST** and I have **location** (say India which is +5:30) so I want to get time which will be in this case **"8:32:32 PM"**

Comment: please, provide your code...

Comment: I don't think code is requred. If still  please specify which code you need.

Comment: One line solution. DateFormat('kk:mm:a').format(DateTime.parse(data['eventDateTimeUtc'] ).toLocal()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In flutter, the standard date time format should come in the local `DateTime` unless otherwise specified. If you already have the data and you didn't create it then you can parse the time that you get to a `DateTime` object using:

```dart
DateFormat format = new DateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time = format.parse("3:02:32 PM");
time.toLocal();
```

Then to get it back to a string again you can simply go:

```dart
time.toString();
```

The Dart documentation states that

> A DateTime object is anchored either in the UTC time zone or in the local time zone of the current computer when the object is created.

And that,

> Use the methods toLocal and toUtc to get the equivalent date/time value specified in the other time zone.

This is the documentation for [reference.](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Comment: Thanks but after the string in parse() we have to specify time-zone offset. Refer: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html. And again thanx.

Comment: One line solution.

DateFormat('kk:mm:a').format( DateTime.parse(data['eventDateTimeUtc'] ).toLocal()